# Heroku Discord Bot builds but doesn't work when deployed

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, discord, discord.py

I've deployed a Discord bot(discord.py) with heroku. The status of the bot is "online" in the Heroku's Dashboard however the bot is offline in Discord.I've added the Procfile and enabled the dyno in resources.
Is there anything else i have to do??[image]

EDIT:
This is my procfile's content - worker :python bot.py
Requirements.txt:

Comment: The content of your `Procfile` should be `worker: python bot.py`. Share the content of your `Pipfile`, `requirements.txt` or `setup.py`

Comment: requirements.txt-
discord.py == 1.3.4
praw == 7.1.0
youtube_dl == 2020.7.28

Comment: Thank you,there was some problem with my requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can check the heroku logs using the following command in the command Prompt of your PC (you need to have Heroku CLI installed)

`heroku logs -a yourappnamehere`

any errors in the running of the bot will be displayed there, if there are no errors displayed in the logs, you can check the following:

1.you have put in the bot's token correctly,

2.you have put in the `bot.run(token)` line at the end of your code

3.any mistakes in the Procfile or requirements files (make sure you spell requirements corretly)

4. or just re-deploy your bot, and see if the problem still persists

Comment: The logs says,the bot crashed:
2020-08-04T11:41:58.347677+00:00 app[worker.1]: bash: :python: command not found
2020-08-04T11:41:58.413742+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 127
2020-08-04T11:41:58.444933+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

Answer (score 0):

You could try regenerating your bot token and then redeploy it again. Or maybe you should do git commit -am "fix procfile"

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `worker :python bot.py` to `worker: python bot.py` and make sure your Procfile is spelled and capitalized exactly like `Procfile` (capital P)

Can you open your log and tell us what the error is?

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I have already resolved the issue! Idk how. Can you tell me what this means?
The logs says,the bot crashed: 2020-08-04T11:41:58.347677+00:00 app[worker.1]: bash: :python: command not found 2020-08-04T11:41:58.413742+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 127 2020-08-04T11:41:58.444933+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

Comment: ~~Have you made an accurate `requirements.txt` file?~~

My bad, I see you've solved the issue.